# How to ask Debian not to check last mount time of its file system?

Tags: linux, boot, debian

I'm using Debian 6.0.5. To test a feature of my product, I need to modify the system date&time back and forth frequently. Once a time I set the system date back to one month ago, then I reboot the system, and it reported the last mount time of the file system is in the future and enter the maintenance mode automatically. I had to run the fsck to make sure the file system is not broken to boot into Debian.

Is there any way to ask Debian stop checking the last mount time of its file system when booting? Thanks.

P.S. Most of my disk partition are in ext4 format, and the others are in 'ntfs' format.

Comment: Is it necessary to reboot the whole system to test your service? Perhaps you can simply restart your service.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bypassing-fsck/) has some recommendations if you have filesystems other than ext3/4

List all ext3 and ext4 filesystems:

```
mount -t ext4 | awk '{print $1}'
mount -t ext3 | awk '{print $1}'
```

For each one run tune2fs on it:

```
tune2fs -c -1 -i 0 /dev/sda1
```

This command will set the mount interval and last check time to values that keep fsck from running

Comment: This prevents automatic checking, but does not prevent the "sanity" checks run on startup.

Comment: @flashnode: Thank you. One point I forgot to mention is that one of my mounted file system is 'ntfs'. It looks like tune2fs only applies for ext2/ext3/ext4. Is there a similar tool specific for ntfs? Thanks.

Comment: @Landy: I edited my answer with a very good article.

Comment: @flashnode: Thank you. You really helped me a lot! ;-)